# Object spread equivalent in C#?

Tags: c#, .net

I have this code:

```
        invoiceSurcharges.Result = from surcharge in invoiceSurcharges.Result
                                   select new ListInvoiceSurchargesGridByInvoice
                                   {
                                       
                                   };
```

Now, I would like to modify just one property of `surcharge` without having to assign each property of the object to the new one. It would be ideal if I could do something like:

```
        invoiceSurcharges.Result = from surcharge in invoiceSurcharges.Result
                                   select new ListInvoiceSurchargesGridByInvoice
                                   {
                                       ...surcharge,
                                       AssociatedInvoice = $"{surcharge.InvoiceSerial}-{surcharge.InvoiceYear}"
                                   };
```

Is there any way I could do this in C#?

Comment: If you use a `record`, you can use [`with`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/with-expression). If not, `with` won't work and you'd have to write your own clone method or awkward constructors (or an anonymous type if you stay inside one method, since C# 10 extends `with` to those).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a copy constructor to `ListInvoiceSurchargesGridByInvoice` that copies all the properties from the sucharge object. You can still use property initializers to override specific properties. Consider making your objects immutable, and properties [init-only](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-9.0/init), that helps avoid unintended mutation of your objects.

But an easier method is probably to use records, they are trivial to make immutable, and come with the [with-expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/sv-se/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/with-expression) to help creating copies with a minimal of boiler plate code:

```
public record ListInvoiceSurchargesGridByInvoice{
  public string AssociatedInvoice { get; init; }
  ...
}
```

```
invoiceSurcharges.Result = from surcharge in invoiceSurcharges.Result
select surcharge with { AssociatedInvoice = $"{surcharge.InvoiceSerial}-{surcharge.InvoiceYear}"};
```

There are some caveats when using records with EntityFramework. If that is a concern I would recommend doing some further research.